# Transaction management in a SOAP server implementation

Tags: hibernate, spring, session, soap

I have a standard jax-ws webservice set up that uses Spring for DI and Hibernate for persistence. Now in Spring you'd normally wrap your request in a custom filter and execute `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` / `rollback()` on the Hibernate session depending whether the execution went through without errors or not.

For the soap web client however, this execution chain is not used and therefor no transaction management can easily be set up like this. Of course I also want to avoid wrapping each of my `@WebMethod` implementations in

```
session.beginTransaction();
try {
   ... 
   session.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
   session.rollback();
   throw e;
}
```

so I looked into other possibilities. Apparently the JSR allows to configure `SOAPHandler`'s (via `@HandlerChain`) that intercept SOAP traffic after incoming and before outgoing soap messages are sent, but I wonder if I am on the right track with that or doing it wrong...

Do you guys know of other alternatives?

---

I went down the `SOAPHandler` route and it seems to work nicely:

```
public class SOAPServiceHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext mc)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc)
    {
        MyHibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc)
    {
        Session session = MyHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (!outbound)
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
            return true;
        }

        SOAPBody body = null;
        try
        {
            body = smc.getMessage().getSOAPBody();
        }
        catch (SOAPException e)
        {
        }

        session.flush();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);

        if (body == null || body.hasFault())
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        else
        {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
    xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd"> 

    <bean id="SoapServiceImpl" class="path.to.SOAPServiceImpl" />       
    <bean id="SoapServiceHandler" class="path.to.SOAPServiceHandler" /> 

    <wss:binding url="/soap">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#SoapServiceImpl">
                <ws:handlers>
                    <ref bean="SoapServiceHandler" />
                </ws:handlers>
            </ws:service>
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>
</beans>
```

Feedback welcome!